# Availability of CHROOT in Docker containers and clusters

Tags: linux, docker, cluster, cloud, chroot

Is the Linux tool `chroot` generally usable in a Docker container running in clusters and cloud platforms?

*(background)* I'm developing an application where I may need to use `chroot` inside a Docker container. In a [related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/271856/297040) I expressed my confusion about `chroot` and the `SYS_CHROOT` Linux capability, which may or may not be required anymore to run `chroot` and may or may not be granted by default by Docker. That's why I think I have to tell system administrators when deploying my applications to specify `--cap-add SYS_CHROOT` to Docker in case it's not granted by default. But that's a command line argument of `docker run` and I don't know if I can give it for granted that most cloud providers and cluster administrators will be able to grant the `SYS_CHROOT` capability to my container. Basically I'm trying to predict issues that a system administrator may encounter when trying to install my application without being able to easily contact me for example.

Comment: Why would you need chroot INSIDE a container?

Comment: I don't need *one* chroot, I need many of them inside one container, as a possible solution I'm focused on as explained in my related, linked question: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/271856/297040.

Comment: The common way is to use a container per task.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider your comment is interesting because containers are a very different path that I'm already following as an alternative, except I think it's common to use a container per *service* and not per *task* or job. My jobs are very short-lived (milliseconds) and I also look for some performance. Do you have sources, references, examples or anything? Thanks

Comment: Also, a container per task may also involve copying files. The performance drawback may be uncomparable to that of a simpler chroot.

Comment: People who are upvoting the comment of Gerald can also explain their opinion?